# Vba: Regular expression to count the number of words in a string delimited by special characters

Tags: regex, vba, excel

Need some help writing a regular expression to count the number of words in a **string** (Please note the data is a **html string**, which needs to be placed into a spreadsheet)  when separated either by any special characters like **.** , **-** , **+**, **/**, **Tab** etc. Count should exclude special characters.

```
     **Original String**             **End Result**
Ex :   One                    ->       1
       One.                   ->       1
       One Two                ->       2
       One.Two                ->       2
       One Two.               ->       2
       One.Two.               ->       2
       One.Tw.o               ->       3
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? This is not the place where you can get your work done. Please show us that you have tried something and having problem anywhere in your try.

Comment: If the separating characters are the same in one string, you can use `Split` function to achieve something like this. Otherwise the only method come up to my mind is by building a comparing string with all possible special characters. Then scan through the string for counting how many special characters are there in the string. And lastly check the part of the string after the last special character to decided +1 or not.

Comment: @newacc2240 I've tried the split function but the problem is when the string changes every time when special characters  . + * - _ could be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

I think you asked a valuable question and this downvoting is not fair!

```
Function WCount(ByVal strWrd As String) As Long
    'Variable declaration
    Dim Delimiters() As Variant
    Dim Delimiter As Variant

    'Initialization
    Delimiters = Array("+", "-", ".", "/", Chr(13), Chr(9)) 'Define your delimiter characters here.

    'Core
    For Each Delimiter In Delimiters
        strWrd = Replace(strWrd, Delimiter, " ")
    Next Delimiter
    strWrd = Trim(strWrd)

    Do While InStr(1, strWrd, "  ") > 0
        strWrd = Replace(strWrd, "  ", " ")
    Loop

    WCount = UBound(Split(strWrd, " ")) + 1

End Function
```

**________________**

You can use this function as a `UDF` in excel formulas or can use in another `VBA` codes.

- **Using in formula**

`=WCOUNT("One.Two.Three.")` or `=WCOUNT($A$1")` assuming your string is in A1 cell.

- **Using in VBA**

(With assume passing your string with `Str` argument.)

```
Sub test()

    Debug.Print WCount(Str)

End Sub
```

Regards.

### Update

I have test your text as shown below.

copy your text in a Cell of Excel as shown.

The code updated for `Line break` and `Tab` characters and count your string words correctly now.

[image: Excel]

[image: Code]

Comment: Wow. That's awesome. Let's see if this can be done using a regular expression as well. Thanks.

Comment: @QTMA the down votes that you are seeing are for efforts shown by Original Poster per this forum general rules. It is different thing that I have not voted down this post.

Comment: If my answer solve the problem, Please accept by clicking on accept icon in the right side of answer below of voting tool.

Comment: @ShrivallabhaRedij Its funny how the up/downvoting works!

Comment: @VishalKumar I just informed what caused it. Opinions are ultimately individual thing. I am happy that OP has a working solution!

Comment: @ShrivallabhaRedij I got that. Thanks for your time. Have a nice day. Bye. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, all necessary comments are in code:

```
Sub SpecialSplit()
Dim i As Long
Dim str As String
Dim arr() As String
Dim delimeters() As String
'here you define all special delimeters you want to use
delimetres = Array(".", "+", "-", "/")
For i = 1 To 9
    str = Cells(i, 1).Value
    'this will protect us from situation where last character is delimeter and we have additional empty string
    str = Left(str, Len(str) - 1)
    'here we replace all special delimeters with space to simplify
    For Each delimeter In delimetres
         str = Replace(str, delimeter, " ")
    Next
    arr = Split(str)
    Cells(i, 2).Value = UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Michal Turczyn, but the data is a html string. Sorry, for not making that clear in my question.

Comment: Then post your example html file. And also desired output - shuold it be in Excel or another html or...?

Comment: Turczyn Please see above

Comment: Ok, I get it now, but you also need to provide full html :)

Comment: This answer is false and involves `Run-Time` error in `mismatch variable type` and magical bug. in line `delimetres = Array(".", "+", "-", "/")` when using `Array` function, data type should be `Variant`; and in logic of your code if `str` involves many spaces as `"    One   .   Two   .   Three."` works false. And if the `str` starts or ends with `delimiter`.

Answer (score 0):

With your posted data following RegExp is working correctly. Put this in General Module in Visual Basic Editor.

```
Public Function CountWords(strInput As String) As Long
Dim objMatches
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = "\w+"
    Set objMatches = .Execute(strInput)
    CountWords = objMatches.Count
End With
End Function
```

You have to use it like a normal formula. e.g. assuming data is in cell A1 function would be:

`=CountWords(A1)`

For your information, it can be also achieved through formula if number of characters are specific like so:

`=LEN(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1),"."," "),","," "),"-"," "),"+"," "),"/"," "),"\"," ")))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1),"."," "),","," "),"-"," "),"+"," "),"/"," "),"\"," "))," ",""))+1`

Comment: The formula has bug, when the string contains multiple spaces within, the `CountWords` Public Function is perfect!

Comment: @QTMA TRIM inside takes care of it. I have tested the formula before posting.

Comment: @ShrivallabhaRedij Well, the number of characters are not specific. Will check your CountWords function. Thanks.

Comment: @ShrivallabhaRedij, This formula returns number of letters.